# DB2 Build Json document with about two columns

Tags: db2

I want to generate a json file based on the result of this query.
But as a result I will get exactly 10 rows as CLOB. But I want only one.

```
select json_object (
'ID' value id, 'NAME' value name) 
FROM OBJECTS
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

It should has an output like this

```
{
objects: 
{id:1, name: a
},
{id:2, name: b
}
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what the json object should look like?

Comment: Have you tried something like `SELECT JSON_ARRAY(... SELECT you query above...)`? You would need to create another JSON_OBJECT with the array as KV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some guessing:

```
values (json_array(select json_object ('ID' value id, 'NAME' value name)
                   from objects
                   fetch first 10 rows only
                  )
       )
```

AFAIK, you need an array to store a collection of things:

```
values json_object( 'objects' value (json_array
       (select json_object ('ID' value id, 'NAME' value name)
        from objects
        fetch first 10 rows only
       )
   ));
```

Comment: Can I assign the result to a JSON type, like
`DECLARE result JSON;
SET result = ...values`

Comment: JSON is not a type in Db2, but you can store it in a VARCHAR, CLOB, BLOB (use JSON_TO_BSON function on result)

Comment: Is it also possible to ask such a json, how much entries are in the json?

Comment: Yes, if it is an array I believe the function is JSON_LEN

Comment: Got an error like 
**{0:0} No authorized routine named "JSON_LEN" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.28.11**
My usage

`DECLARE ret CLOB(10M);
SET ret = (values (
json_array(
select json_object ('ID' value id, 'NAME' value name
  )
FROM OBJECTS
)))
--this call failed
JSON_LEN(ret)
;`

Comment: You can find some examples at:  https://notebook.community/DB2-Samples/db2jupyter/Db2%20JSON%20Features